# How to write URL rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

When no file or dir found: /user or /user/xxx to user.php/xxx, /admin or /admin/xxx to admin.php/xxx, else to index.php

Not 301 rewrite, just internal rewrite

I wrote these but error occured:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(user|admin)/?(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [QSA,PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Comment: RewriteCond affects only one RewriteRule, so you need to repeat them before the second RewriteRule

Comment: It works, thank you